# Using geom_label_repel failed to align when faceted with pie chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to build a piechart faceted but labeled with geom_label_repel.  Calculating the position seems to work without facet but fails to align when its splitted into two groups.  For example.

```
library ( ggplot2)
library ( ggrepel )
library ( dplyr)

df = read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/lc3xyuvjjkyeacv/inputpie.csv?dl=1")

df <- df %>% group_by(fac)  %>%
    mutate(
        cs = rev(cumsum(rev(per))),
        text_yp = per/2 + lead(cs, 1),
        text_yp = if_else(is.na(text_yp), per/2, text_yp)
    )  %>%  data.frame()



ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=per, fill=type )) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1) +
    coord_polar("y", start=0)   + 
    facet_grid(fac~.  ) + 
    theme_void()   +
    geom_label_repel(
        aes(
            label = text_y, y = text_yp
        )
        
    )
```

Ideally all the color labels should match up with its respected slice but it fails here.  Any suggestions? thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set factor prior to `ggplot` statement as

```
df$type <- factor(df$type, levels=unique(df$type))
```

Then you get this output:

[image: output]

Comment: perfect, thanks. So the issue here was that the facet order was not correct and thereby switching the rotational order for each facet.